# Catching Error in File c#

Tags: c#

I have this code and I was wondering if there was a way to catch if the file updated contains anything other than numbers separated by a tab or just one number per line.

```
private void complexDataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar1.Value = 0; // Reset progress bar

    this.progressBar1.Value = 0; // Reset progress bar 
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog(); // Initialize open file dialog 
    ofd.Filter = "TXT File|*.txt|PROPL File (*.propl_1178)|*.propl_1178"; // Set acceptable files 
    ofd.Title = "Open File";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);          

        var result2 = text.Split(" \r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)?.Select(num => double.Parse(num)).OrderBy(d => d).ToArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < result2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Lines_Check.Checked == true && i >= Start_Line.Value - 1)
            {
                if (End_Check.Checked == false)
                {
                    Sorted_Box.Text += result2[i] + ", ";
                }
            }// end if   

            if (Lines_Check.Checked == true && i >= Start_Line.Value - 1)
            {
                if (End_Check.Checked == true && i <= End_Line.Value - 1)
                {
                    Sorted_Box.Text += result2[i] + ", ";
                }
            }

            if (Lines_Check.Checked == false)
            {
                Sorted_Box.Text += result2[i] + ", ";
            }                    
        }

    }
} // end complex data
```

Comment: What is this? `dsfdfsdfdfdsfdfdsfdsfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`

Comment: It said I have too much code compared to words so I had to add more words

Comment: Ok, nevermind... so, you want to know if your file is clean (that is either having all numbers separated by tabs or single number per line) or not?

Comment: Yes, I added this to my code: `var result2 = text.Split(" \r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)?.Select(num =>
                    {
                        double result;
                        if (!double.TryParse(num, out result))
                        {
                            // error set result to value other than zero if you need to 
                            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid File Format!");


                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                    ).OrderBy(d => d).ToArray();`

Comment: But now it continually loops through the message box if the file is invalid

Answer (score 0):

If i take your description of the correct file format literally i.e. the file can either be a single line containing only tab delimited digit sequences, or if the file contains multiple lines then each line can only contain a single digit sequence -

```
var isValid = true;
if (lines.Length == 1)
{
    // must be tab delimited list of numbers
    isValid = lines[0].Split('\t').All(x => x.All(y => Char.IsDigit(y)));
}
else if (lines.Length > 1)
{
    // each line must contain a digit sequence only
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        isValid = line.All(z => Char.IsDigit(z));
        if (!isValid)
            break;
    }
}
```

a looser interpretation of what you said would be that the file is valid if it contains any number of lines and any line can contain any number of delimited digit sequences, and additional spaces or tabs, or even empty lines are allowed, then -

```
var isValid = true;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    isValid = line.Split('\t', ' ').Select(x => x.Trim()).All(y => y.All(z => Char.IsDigit(z)));
    if (!isValid)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result2 = text.Split(" \r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)?.Select(num => { double result; if (!double.TryParse(num, out result)) { // error set result to value other than zero if you need to System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid File Format!"); } return result; } ).OrderBy(d => d).ToArray();
```